# Cypress v10 baseUrl configuation

Tags: javascript, cypress

In cypress v10 how can i get to setup differnt environments for diferent URLs, for example I have 3 mayor sites INTEGRATION, STAGE, PRODUCTION, and I have my tests for INTEGRATION, but If I want to Test some part of STAGE or PRODUCTION, I have to change the baseUrl by hand y the cypress.config.js, is there a way to do it in separated files? like older versions, btw the documentation is not clear about that.
older versions I had this.

```
file name: stage-config.json:
```

content:

```
{
"extends": "./cypress.json",
"baseUrl": "https://www.staging-website.com"
}
```

or

```
file name: prod-config.json:
```

content:

```
{
"extends": "./cypress.json",
"baseUrl": "https://www.production-webs.com"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This section of the docs shows one way [Environment - Using 'baseUrl'](https://docs.cypress.io/guides/guides/environment-variables#We-can-move-this-into-a-Cypress-environment-variable)

> **Using 'baseUrl'**
>
> Environment variables are great at pointing to external services and servers, or storing password or other credentials.
>
> However, you do not need to use environment variables to point to the origin and domain under test. Use baseUrl instead of environment variables.
>
> cy.visit() and cy.request() are automatically prefixed with this value - avoiding the need to specify them.
>
> baseUrl can be set in the Cypress configuration file - and then you can set an environment variable in your OS to override it like shown below.
>
> `CYPRESS_BASE_URL=https://staging.app.com cypress run`

You could incorporate that into the `package.json` scripts

```js
// package.json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "cy:staging: : "CYPRESS_BASE_URL=https://staging.app.com cypress run",
    ...
}
```